# No such file or directory using Ansible module lxc_container

Tags: ansible, lxc

I tried starting a simple LXC container - first example in [Manage LXC Containers — Ansible Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/lxc_container_module.html)

```
- name: Create started container
  lxc_container:
    name: test-container-started
    container_log: true
    template: ubuntu
    state: started
    template_options: --release trusty
```

This produces error message

> TASK [lxc : Create started container]
> ****************************************** fatal: [lxc]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "command": "/bin/lxc-create --name
> test-container-started --quiet --template ubuntu --bdev dir --logfile
> /var/log/lxc/lxc-test-container-started.log --logpriority INFO --
> --release trusty", "err": "", "msg": "Failed executing lxc-create.", "rc": 1}

As it turns out `/bin/lxc-create` does not exist on my CentOS 7 VM. The path is actually `/usr/bin/lxc-create`

How can I fix this? Is this a bug in Ansible module lxc_container?